# Laravel 7 No puedo obtener el valor de Auth::user() en blade

Tags: php, laravel, login

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto usando Laravel, y con respecto al login he decidido usar lo que se conoce como 'custom login', ya que el que crea el framework me ocasionaba algún que otro fallo.

Es cuando el usuario hace el login donde aparece el problema. Cuando el usuario inicia sesión es redirigido al perfil, sin embargo, no lo hace. Dejo las rutas para más detalle:

```
Route::view('/home', 'home')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::view("/registro", 'user.signUpForm')->name('signUpForm');
    Route::post("registro", 'signUpController@signUp')->name('user.signUp');
    Route::view('/login', 'user.loginForm')->name('loginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::view('/perfil', 'user.profile')->name('user.profile');
});
```

En el controlador uso la función `Auth::attempt` para comparar la información que se recibe del formulario de login con los datos que se encuentran en la base de datos, para comprobar si se encuentra registrado. Aquí tengo la función login del controlador:

```
    public function Login()
{

    if ($this->validateFields()) {

        $credentials = array(
            "email" => request('email'),
            'password' => request('password')
        );


        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Redirect::intended(route('user.profile'));
        } else {
            return back()
                ->with('error', 'No se pudo iniciar sesión');
        }

    }

    die('no es valido');

}
```

También dejo la vista del perfil, para comprobar lo que hago:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->string('username', 50);
        $table->string('email', 150);
        $table->string('password', 500);
        $table->string('profileImage', 500)->default(null);
        $table->boolean('admin')->default('0');
        $table->increments('ID');

        $table->unique('id', 'id');
    });
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos como tienes configurado tu guard para que funcione con el Auth attempt? Es más común que el error venga de ahí que de tu modelo.

Comment: Te refieres al método guard?

Comment: No, como definiste el guard para el "custom login"? Probablemente la ruta donde haces el login no esté usando el mismo que usas en la página a la que rediriges.

Comment: La verdad es que no configuré nada amigo. Siendo sincero, desconocía que tuviera que hacerlo si usaba un login customizado. ¿Cómo debería configurarlo?

Comment: El problema podría ser más que no está reconociendo el login que hiciste donde recibes las credenciales, sin saber como tienes tus rutas de interés actuales, que middleware y guard están usando sólo podemos especular. Lee la documentación de la autenticación de Laravel ahí explica a bastante detalle lo que tienes a tu alcance, probablemente con eso ubiques que detalle te falta.

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: Tal vez te sirva tratar de entender lo que no te funciona con el login original y modificarlo para utilizarlo, es menos probable que haya errores. Veo que los campos son los mismos que los del login original (email y password), la redirección la modificas en LoginController para ir al perfil.

Comment: Exactamente Fabián, los campos son los mismos, sin embargo, el login original (supongo que también te refieres al predeterminado cuando ejecutas el comando auth) también me daba el mismo fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esta linea:

```
return Redirect::intended(route('user.profile'));
```

Por esta:

```
return redirect()->route('user.profile');
```

en la version de laravel 7, no es necesario usar Redirect para realizar redirecciones, basta con escribir redirect(), es mas simple y mucho mas legible el codigo

Comment: en la version de laravel 7, no es necesario usar Redirect para realizar redirecciones, basta con escribir redirect(), es mas simple y mucho mas legible el codigo